# Can say $g(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{p/2}$ is smooth at origin?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $$g(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^{p/2}$$ for $p\in (0, \infty)\setminus 2\mathbb N.$

> My Question: Can we say $g$ is not infinitely many times   differential at $(0, 0)$? How to justify this?

Comment: For $p=1$ it is not even continuous in $(0,0)$.

Comment: @zkutch: Thanks. I think there is no singularity at origin. Then why does it fail to be  continuous? Please can you explain bit more?

Comment: @zkutch No, it pretty much is continuous at the origin, as it's the product of two continuous functions (the projection map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and the Euclidean metric function on $\mathbb R^2$). In fact, these functions should be continuous everywhere for all of the values of $p$ in the range specified.

Comment: Consider what $g$ looks like along the $x$-axis, i.e., set $y=0$. It's easy to work out the higher derivatives of this restriction of $g$ and to see what goes wrong at the origin once you differentiate more than $p$ times.

Comment: @Learn. Sorry. I think about $p=-1$ and see now it is not allow.